# Proguard not obfuscating Android apps

Tags: java, android, proguard

According to this link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html, they state:

> ProGuard makes your application harder to reverse engineer, it is important that you use it when your application utilizes features that are sensitive to security like when you are Licensing Your Applications.

But that's not true! I'm using the newest Proguard (4.7) included in ADT 17 preview 4. I use proguard while exporting my app by adding

```
proguard.config=proguard-android.txt
```

Into my project.properties (proguard-android.txt is just the default setup included in ADT 17).

But I can easily reverse engineer my apk, returning it to it's original code using these steps:

1. Use apk-tool to extract the apk.
2. Use [smali](http://code.google.com/p/smali/) to convert the .smali files into a .dex (you point smali to the **folder** containing the .smali files, normally inside /src/com/[companyname]/[appname])
3. Use dex2jar to convert the resulting .dex file into a .jar
4. Use jd-gui to view the resulting .jar file

So my question is: am I doing something wrong? Or is proguard just completely useless at obfuscating code?

Comment: It just says harder to reverse-engineer, but it is not impossible to do it just like what you have done. I see people use it primarily to reduce the code size.

Comment: haha I'd love to know their definition of "easy" then. Any app can be reverse engineered in 4 commands! I could train a monkey to do that.

Comment: Just to clarify, what is it that you're seeing in `jd-gui`, and what do you expect to see?  Do you see the original code like, roughly, how you compiled it?  Are you seeing the original variable names in your methods, etc?

Comment: @Logan: Does it change variable, method and some class name (Except Activity name, service name...) ? Proguard only do: shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates (Obfuscates mean rename variable and method ...)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using android.support.* compatibility libraries this can be a root of a problem.
Add the following lines to your proguard config file:

```
-dontwarn android.support.**
-keep class android.support.** { *; }
```

The easiest way to diagnose proguard issues is building an app with apache ant. You'll see all warnings and errors in stderr.

This is appliable to all libraries that use dynamic class loading, reflection and multiple implementations of the same class dependent of API version.